# Hashing Functions and Hash Tables

Tags: java, arrays, hash

> Suppose we have a set of keys: <54, 18, 10, 25, 28, 36, 38, 41, 12,
>   90>.  Use the hashing function *key % N* to map each key into the
>   following array. If there is a collision, use the separate chaining
>   technique.

And below is just the pictorial of the array with the array labelled `A` and it is of size 13 so the picture is the array cells listed 0-12. N=13.

My understanding so far of hashing for this problem is that I need to arrange the keys given into the array using the function `key % 13` (N being equal to 13). But my book doesn't give examples of different functions. The only example it uses is an alphabetizing one with first letters of last names.

Can anyone give me a brief explanation without just giving me the answer?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Choosing_a_good_hash_function - you hash the key to a number then modulo it to pick a bucket (array index)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned,your hash function is h=key%13;

Suppose there is Memory location starting from address 0 to 20.
So apply this function for every element in your array.
1) h1= 54 % 13 = 2 => This will go to the 2nd address location.

2) h2= 18 % 13 = 5 => This will go to the 5th location.

3) h3= 10 % 13 = 10 => This will go to 10th location.

4) h4= 25 % 13 = 14 => This will go to 14th location.

5) h5= 28 % 13 = 2 => Here Collision occurred as 54 is already present at 2nd location.

Now Solution is to use Separate Chaining.

Separate Chaining means just adding this current element to the next location in the Linked List of 2nd Location. Means a new Linked List is meantained at every location when there is Collision.

Below is pictorial ex. of separate chaining.[image]

Hope You got a answer.In above figure elements are different but it will work same.

For more details go to this link : [enter link description here](http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ics/saquib/ICS202/Unit29_Hashing2.pdf)

Comment: That pp is very helpful in explaining too, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You appear to understanding the general process of inserting a value into a hash.  All you need to do is relate your textbook example to your homework assignment question.

1. Determine which bucket you need to put the value in based on the hashing function.  In the textbook example, the hashing function is taking the first letter of the last name.  In your assignment, the hashing function is N % 13.
2. Resolve any collisions and perform the actual insertion.  You don't mention what your textbook example uses as a collision resolution strategy, but your assignment asks you to use separate chaining.

Comment: So, take the first key, 54, divide it by 13 and the resulting int (rounded I'm guessing) is the bucket I put that key in?

Comment: Well, you would % it because that's what the assignment says (if you to divide, then you should always round down to save yourself from choosing whether to round down or up).  But you have the right idea.

Comment: Oh wait! Duh sorry, modulus result is the remainder. Forgot about that.

Comment: It the modulus result an absolute value or can it be negative?

Comment: modulus in Java can be negative.  So you can handle this case by taking the absolute value or adding N to it.